# How to get the key of array having same title and merge it in the same array

Tags: php

```
"categories": [
  {
    "title": "тест",
    "ids": [
      1
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "тест",
    "ids": [
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "тест2",
    "ids": [
      3
    ]
  }
]
```

There is this array. It is necessary in case of matching of keys "title "to unite in one array and to write id. I need to get an array of the following kind:

```
"categories": [
  {
    "title": "тест",
    "ids": [
      1,
      2
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "тест2",
    "ids": [
      3
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: If you can, do this via your database. This can be done in PHP, but with large objects, this will get slow

Comment: Your question's tag is "php" but your arrays seems to be javascript objects, no?

Comment: The perfect case for the PHP function [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $categories = [
            [
                "title" => "test1",
                 "ids"  => [1]
            ],
            [
                "title" => "test1",
                "ids"  => [2]
            ],
            [
                "title" => "test2",
                "ids"  => [3]
            ],
        ];

        $result = [];
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if (isset($result[$category['title']])){
                $result[$category['title']]["ids"] = array_merge($result[$category['title']]["ids"], $category["ids"]);
            } else {
                $result[$category['title']] = $category;
            }
        }

        var_dump(array_values($result));
```